# IR signal: different libs, different bit/byte ordering?

Tags: infrared

For IR sender at Nano Every (ATMega4809-based) I am using infrared4arduino to send simple remote control codes. I am double-checking those with a Nano-based receiver with IRrecvDumpV2 example from IRremote library but I am receiving something else what I am sending (I think):

The sender has the following code using Infrared4Arduino:

```
   IrSignal* sig=Nec1Renderer::newIrSignal(0,0x906f); // cmd 0x90
   IrSenderPwm::getInstance(true)->sendIrSignal(*sig,1);
```

but the receiver dumps (besides some garbage like 0-bit `JVC` and `SANYO` frames):

```
Encoding  : NEC
Code      : FFF609 (32 bits)
unsigned int  data = 0xFFF609;
```

`0x00` and `0xff` (first 2 bytes of the "packet") are device and its logical complement, those are fine.

The command sent as `0x90` (followed by its logical complement `0x6f`) is decoded as `0xF6` (plus its logical complement `0x09`). Why? Is it an accident that `906f` is `f609` backwards?

What's going on here?

I will try to run both sender and receiver with the same lib (IRremote is not ported to Nano Every) but before I go ahead, better ask. Perhaps I am only doing some IR-beginner's mistake.

Comment: `The command sent as 0x90 (followed by its logical complement 0x6f) ` ... how do you know this?

Comment: you picked data that reads the same no  matter which is the bit order ... `1001` is same both directions ... transmit code, such as `1000`

Comment: @jsotola That's the way the protocol works, as far as I understand. Device ID (`0x00` in this case), its bit complement `0xff` (for redundancy) and then command `0x90` (`0b10010000`) and its bit complenment `0x6f` (`0b01101111`, again for redundancy).

Comment: you chose symmetrical data ... 10010000 reads 0x90 in one bit order and 0x09 in the other bit order, so it is not obvious how the data is being transmitted and received ... instead choose something like 11000100 which reads 0xC4 in one bit order and 0x23 in the other bit order

Comment: Solved, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It is the receiver (IRremote-based) which is decoding bits in reverse order. IRremote and IRLib2 implement the NEC protocol incorrectly (both on sending and receiving sides). More details in the issue report https://github.com/bengtmartensson/Infrared4Arduino/issues/52 .